# How to conditionally add style attribute to template in angular?

Tags: angular

I've seen examples of how to create a conditional style.  However I do not want the style attribute to appear in some cases.  This is what I want:

```
<div class="backgroundGradient" [style.backgroundImage]="myBackgroundImageUrl"></div>
```

However this issue here is when the `myBackgroundImageUrl` doesn't exist.  I want `backgroundGradient` to show up.  The problem here is angular will just display `<div style="background-image: none">`.  In chrome debugger if I remove this - my code works.

I basically don't want the style attribute to show up at all if `myBackgroundImageUrl` doesn't exist.  Ternary doesn't work here either.

I want to know if its possible to do this without using 2 elements with *ngIf.  That is worst case scenario but by element has a ton more attributes so I'm trying to avoid replicating unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
<div class="backgroundGradient" [ngStyle]="myStyle"></div>
```

componenet.ts

```
myStyle:any

ngOnInit() {
  if (hasImage) {
  this.myStyle={'background-image':url}
  }
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle